# Visualizar arquivos do diretório - PHP

Tags: php

Boa tarde, possuo um sistema de cadastro de arquivos mensais, atualmente os arquivos são exibidos através de um `href` redirecionando ao caminho do arquivo (diretório), dando para baixa-los.

**Quero visualizar/abrir esses arquivos, sem precisar baixa-los.**

Achei um vídeo, e acompanhei, porém a pagina não está respondendo...
[LINK DO VÍDEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SwCfnHCR6Ks)

**Alguém tem alguma outra solução? ou me dizer aonde estou errando?**

**Meu arquivo: `listagem_relatorio_psi.php`**

```
<?php  
        include('menu.php');

?> 


<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
$('#dtHorizontalExample').DataTable({
"scrollX": true
});
$('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');
});

</script>         



       <!-- LISTAGEM  -->  
       <div class="main-content">
              <h3><center><i><b> Listagem relatórios psicologia<b></i></center></h3>
                <div class="section__content section__content--p30">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">


       <table class="table table-borderless table-striped table-earning" id="dtHorizontalExample" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

    <thead>
      <th class="th-sm">Paciente
      </th>

      <th class="th-sm">Janeiro
      </th>

      <th class="th-sm">Editar
      </th>

      <th class="th-sm">Excluir
    </th>     

   </tr>

</thead>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
  <tbody>

<?php
require('conexaobd.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM relatorio_psi";

$resultado = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

$inc = 0;


while ($cont = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
    echo "
        <tr>
                <td>".$cont['paciente']."</td>  


                <td><a href='visualizar_arquivo.php?codigo_relatorio=".$cont['codigo_relatorio']."' target='_blank'><img src='https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-colorful-icons/360/google_docs.png' style='width:30px; height:30px;cursor:pointer;'></a></td>

                <td> 
                 <a href='edit_relatorio_psi.php?codigo_relatorio=".$cont['codigo_relatorio']."&paciente=".$cont['paciente']." target='new_blank'>
                <span class='role blue'> 
               <i class='fa fa-edit'></i>
                </span>
                </a>
                </td>

                <td> 
                 <a href='del_relatorio_psi.php?paciente=".$cont['paciente']."' target='new_blank' confirm='Tem certeza que deseja deletar essa internação?'>
                <span class='role red'> 
                <i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i> 
                </span>
                </a>
                </td>
                </tr>
        </tr>
    ";
}
?>
```

**Meu arquivo: `visualizar_arquivo.php`**

```
<?php
    require('conexaobd.php');

    $codigo_relatorio = $_GET["codigo_relatorio"];


    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM relatorio_psi WHERE codigo_relatorio = $codigo_relatorio");

    $query = mysqli_fetch_object($result);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){


        $pasta = "uploads_psi/".$query->codigo_relatorio;

        if (file_exists($pasta)) {

            header('Content-Type: application/docx');
            header('Content-disposition: inline; filename='.$query->codigo_relatorio);
            readfile($pasta);


        }else{
            echo "Não foi possivel encontrar o arquivo na diretório!";
        }

    }

?>
```

Comment: Você recebe alguma mensagem de erro?

Comment: Mostra um `dump` da variável `$query`.

Comment: Olá @KayoBruno, a pagina simplesmente não responde... sou "novo" em programação, mas acho que a parte `$query->codigo_relatorio;` esteja errado... não sei